# Unable to display profile userid and email

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a profile page. However, as of now, my app's profile userid and email is not coming out on my page. There are no errors on my profile when I check the console. Is there any way I can solve this?

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

getProfile(); //execute getProfile() to get user's profile
});
//Profile Section
function getProfile() {
    var url = serverURL() + "/getuser.php"; //execute getprofile.php

    var JSONObject = {
        "userid": localStorage.getItem("userid") //provide userid to execute getprofile.php
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSONObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            _getProfileResult(arr); //successful call to getprofile.php execute _getProfileResult()
        },
        error: function () {
            validationMsg();
        }
    });
}

function _getProfileResult(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        htmlstring = "<img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "' height='100'><div>";
        $("#txtProfileUsername").html(arr[i].userID);
        $("#txtProfileEmail").html(arr[i].email);
        $("#profileimage").append(htmlstring);

    }


    $("#txtProfileUsername").html("User ID: " + userid); //update <div> with userid
    $("#txtProfileEmail").html("Email: " + email); //update <div> with email
    $("#txtAddress").val(address); //update <div> with  address
    $("#imgProfilePicture").attr("src", serverURL() + "/images/" + profileimage + "_s"); //update <img> with image 
}
```

HTML

```
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="main-ui">
        <div id="profileimage"></div>
        <div id="txtProfileUsername"></div>
        <div id="txtProfileEmail"></div>
```

Comment: I dont see the `localStorage.setItem` for `userid` anywhere

Comment: Why do you have this `$("#txtProfileUsername").html(` within your `for-loop` and outside from it?

Comment: If you using `$("#txtProfileUsername").html(arr[i].userID);
        $("#txtProfileEmail").html(arr[i].email);` in loop then why do you replace value outside it?